# GitAction - Git fetch failed with exit code: 1

Tags: android, git, github

I'm tried to build the Android project with GitAction but got an following error in the checkout step:

> [error]Git fetch failed with exit code: 1
>
> [error]Exit code 1 returned from process: file name
>   '/Users/runner/runners/2.163.1/bin/Runner.PluginHost', arguments
>   'action "GitHub.Runner.Plugins.Repository.v1_0.CheckoutTask,
>   Runner.Plugins"'.

Below is the image is taken from Git-Action:
[image]

Here is my Git-Action set-up:

[image]

Very appreciate to anyone give me some advice on this. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+origin%2Fdev+exists

Comment: In your case the problem is with branches `origin/dev` and `origin/dev/xxx`.